# analyse and store a annotated game by stockfish in scid

Tags: stockfish, scid

Salut

I installed scid and set all necessities in order to make an analysis by stockfish, but I could not find the option to save the done analysis.

My question is just silly but I cannot find simply this function.

Thanks for your answers!

[image]

*could you propose a method whereby I could make analyses of several games by an engine which also stores all analyses so that I could watch later to them?

Answer (score 1):

In the Game menu, there's a Save: Replace Game option.  If you choose this after doing your analysis, the analysis should be saved.